# Ghostly outline around image after resize

Tags: c#, .net, image, resize, scale

I'm working on a website that will sell hand made jewelry and I'm finishing the image editor, but it's not behaving quite right.

Basically, the user uploads an image which will be saved as a source and then it will be resized to fit the user's screen and saved as a temp. The user will then go to a screen that will allow them to crop the image and then save it to it's final versions.

All of that works fine, except, the final versions have 3 bugs. First is some black horizontal line on the very bottom of the image. Second is an outline of sorts that follows the edges. I thought it was because I was reducing the quality, but even at 100% it still shows up... And lastly, I've noticed that the cropped image is always a couple of pixels lower than what I'm specifying...

Anyway, I'm hoping someone whose got experience in editing images with C# can maybe take a look at the code and see where I might be going off the right path.

Oh, by the way, this in an ASP.NET MVC application.

Here's the code:

```
public class ImageProvider {
    private readonly ProductProvider ProductProvider = null;

    private readonly EncoderParameters HighQualityEncoder = new EncoderParameters();
    private readonly ImageCodecInfo JpegCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(
        c => (c.MimeType == "image/jpeg"));

    private readonly string Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/Images/Products");
    private readonly short[][] Dimensions = new short[3][] {
        new short[2] { 640, 480 },
        new short[2] { 240, 0 },
        new short[2] { 80, 60 }
    }

    public ImageProvider(ProductProvider ProductProvider) {
        this.ProductProvider = ProductProvider;

        HighQualityEncoder.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    }

    public void Crop(string FileName, Image Image, Crop Crop) {
        using (Bitmap Source = new Bitmap(Image)) {
            using (Bitmap Target = new Bitmap(Crop.Width, Crop.Height)) {
                using (Graphics Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Target)) {
                    Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                    Graphics.DrawImage(Source, new Rectangle(0, 0, Target.Width, Target.Height), new Rectangle(Crop.Left, Crop.Top, Crop.Width, Crop.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                }

                Target.Save(FileName, JpegCodecInfo, HighQualityEncoder);
            }
        }
    }

    public void CropAndResize(Product Product, Crop Crop) {
        using (Image Source = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.source", Path, Product.ProductId))) {
            using (Image Temp = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId))) {
                float Percent = ((float)Source.Width / (float)Temp.Width);

                short Width = (short)(Temp.Width * Percent);
                short Height = (short)(Temp.Height * Percent);

                Crop.Height = (short)(Crop.Height * Percent);
                Crop.Left = (short)(Crop.Left * Percent);
                Crop.Top = (short)(Crop.Top * Percent);
                Crop.Width = (short)(Crop.Width * Percent);

                Img Img = new Img();

                this.ProductProvider.AddImageAndSave(Product, Img);

                this.Crop(String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId), Source, Crop);

                using (Image Cropped = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId))) {
                    this.Resize(this.Dimensions[0], String.Format("{0}/{1}-L.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), Cropped, HighQualityEncoder);
                    this.Resize(this.Dimensions[1], String.Format("{0}/{1}-T.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), Cropped, HighQualityEncoder);
                    this.Resize(this.Dimensions[2], String.Format("{0}/{1}-S.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), Cropped, HighQualityEncoder);
                }
            }
        }

        this.Purge(Product);
    }

    public void QueueFor( Product Product, HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile) {
        using (Image Image = Image.FromStream(PostedFile.InputStream)) {
            this.Resize(new short[2] {
                1152,
                0
            }, String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId), Image, HighQualityEncoder);
        }

        PostedFile.SaveAs(String.Format("{0}/{1}.source", Path, Product.ProductId));
    }

    private void Purge(Product Product) {
        string Source = String.Format("{0}/{1}.source", Path, Product.ProductId);
        string Temp = String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId);

        if (File.Exists(Source)) {
            File.Delete(Source);
        }
        if (File.Exists(Temp)) {
            File.Delete(Temp);
        }

        foreach (Img Img in Product.Imgs) {
            string Cropped = String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId);

            if (File.Exists(Cropped)) {
                File.Delete(Cropped);
            }
        }
    }

    public void Resize( short[] Dimensions, string FileName, Image Image, EncoderParameters EncoderParameters) {
        if (Dimensions[1] == 0) {
            Dimensions[1] = (short)(Image.Height / ((float)Image.Width / (float)Dimensions[0]));
        }

        using (Bitmap Bitmap = new Bitmap(Dimensions[0], Dimensions[1])) {
            using (Graphics Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap)) {
                Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;

                Graphics.DrawImage(Image, 0, 0, Dimensions[0], Dimensions[1]);
            };

            Bitmap.Save(FileName, JpegCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's one of the images this produces:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJX97.jpg]

**UPDATE**

So, I sat down and read through MSDN for like 2 hours after I posted, verified the code I had. As far as I can tell, I'm using the highest possible quality settings when performing the manipulation.

Either way, I ended up cleaning up and streamlining the code a bit. I contemplated the need for the source file and decided to remove it because it was requiring me to do additional work to figure out the cropping dimensions that are based on the temp file. So, it's gone.

Also, somewhere along the streamlining, the black line disappeared, so I can only assume that the aspect ratio issues should have been corrected as @StefanE stated.

Also, as @VinayC said, the re-sizer was generating a value of 479 for the height (which I still don't get how, but whatever...), but that seems to have been corrected when I switched to using the System.Drawing.Size and System.Drawing.Rectangle classes all the way through instead of using my own classes which essentially do the same thing.

So, here's the updated code. The remaining <s>two bugs</s> bug still stand, so I have a "ghosting" outline all the way around the image (see second attachment) which I can narrow down to the resizing because it shows up in the first re-size where no cropping has occurred. <s>And the second bug is that the cropped versions are always positioned lower on the y axis than what I pass in as the cropper. I'd estimate it's a good 5%-8% lower than what I tell it, so not sure about that one (the positions shouldn't be changing... unless I'm passing in a bad number from jQuery, gotta check on that...).</s>

(My second bug ended up me sending bad values to begin with, the cropping div was getting its relative position based on the master content div, not the image container div. All fixed now.)

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace Website.Models.Providers {
    public class ImageProvider {
        private readonly ProductProvider ProductProvider = null;

        private readonly EncoderParameters DefaultQualityEncoder = new EncoderParameters();
        private readonly EncoderParameters HighQualityEncoder = new EncoderParameters();
        private readonly ImageCodecInfo JpegCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(
            c =>
                (c.MimeType == "image/jpeg"));
        private readonly Size[] Sizes = new Size[3] {
            new Size(640, 0),
            new Size(240, 0),
            new Size(80, 0)
        };

        private readonly string Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/Images/Products");

        public ImageProvider(
            ProductProvider ProductProvider) {
            this.ProductProvider = ProductProvider;

            this.DefaultQualityEncoder.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 80L);
            this.HighQualityEncoder.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
        }

        public void Crop(
            string FileName,
            Image Image,
            Crop Crop) {
            using (Bitmap Source = new Bitmap(Image)) {
                using (Bitmap Target = new Bitmap(Crop.Width, Crop.Height)) {
                    using (Graphics Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Target)) {
                        Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                        Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                        Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

                        Graphics.DrawImage(Source, new Rectangle(0, 0, Target.Width, Target.Height), new Rectangle(Crop.Left, Crop.Top, Crop.Width, Crop.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                    };

                    Target.Save(FileName, JpegCodecInfo, HighQualityEncoder);
                };
            };
        }

        public void CropAndResize(
            Product Product,
            Crop Crop) {
            using (Image Temp = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId))) {
                Img Img = new Img();

                this.ProductProvider.AddImageAndSave(Product, Img);

                this.Crop(String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId), Temp, Crop);

                using (Image Cropped = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId))) {
                    this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}-L.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), this.Sizes[0], Cropped, HighQualityEncoder);
                    this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}-T.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), this.Sizes[1], Cropped, HighQualityEncoder);
                    this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}-S.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), this.Sizes[2], Cropped, HighQualityEncoder);
                };
            };

            this.Purge(Product);
        }

        public void QueueFor(
            Product Product,
            Size Size,
            HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile) {
            using (Image Image = Image.FromStream(PostedFile.InputStream)) {
                this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId), Size, Image, HighQualityEncoder);
            };
        }

        private void Purge(
            Product Product) {
            string Temp = String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId);

            if (File.Exists(Temp)) {
                File.Delete(Temp);
            };

            foreach (Img Img in Product.Imgs) {
                string Cropped = String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId);

                if (File.Exists(Cropped)) {
                    File.Delete(Cropped);
                };
            };
        }

        public void Resize(
            string FileName,
            Size Size,
            Image Image,
            EncoderParameters EncoderParameters) {
            if (Size.Height == 0) {
                Size.Height = (int)(Image.Height / ((float)Image.Width / (float)Size.Width));
            };

            using (Bitmap Bitmap = new Bitmap(Size.Width, Size.Height)) {
                using (Graphics Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Bitmap)) {
                    Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

                    Graphics.DrawImage(Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height));
                };

                Bitmap.Save(FileName, JpegCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);
            };
        }
    }
}
```

This image shows the "ghosting" outline pointed to by red arrows.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news, everyone! I fixed it, and I have to say the solution was so simple it just made me grunt and sigh really hard. Apperantly, in the `Resize` method I was doing *way* more work than was needed to resize an image. The whole `using (Graphics ...)` was the problem. You can just do `using (Bitmap Bitmap = new Bitmap(SOURCE_IMAGE, NEW_SIZE))` and it works.

Clean and simple and it makes me wonder why tutorials on the web (and code I've been using up until now on other projects) force the use of the `Graphics` class when it's not needed?

So, without further a due, here is the final version of my code for anyone who may find it useful. Keep in mind that the `CropAndResize`, `QueueFor` and `Purge` methods are specialized to work with my domain model, but the `Crop` and `Resize` methods which this whole class is ultimately about can easily be adapted to any other application.

Enjoy:

```
public class ImageProvider {
    private readonly ProductProvider ProductProvider = null;

    private readonly EncoderParameters DefaultQualityEncoder = new EncoderParameters();
    private readonly EncoderParameters HighQualityEncoder = new EncoderParameters();
    private readonly ImageCodecInfo JpegCodecInfo = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().Single(
        c =>
            (c.MimeType == "image/jpeg"));
    private readonly Size[] Sizes = new Size[3] {
        new Size(640, 0),
        new Size(280, 0),
        new Size(80, 0)
    };

    private readonly string Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Resources/Images/Products");

    public ImageProvider(
        ProductProvider ProductProvider) {
        this.ProductProvider = ProductProvider;

        this.DefaultQualityEncoder.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 90L);
        this.HighQualityEncoder.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
    }

    private void Crop(
        string FileName,
        Image Image,
        Crop Crop) {
        using (Bitmap Source = new Bitmap(Image)) {
            Source.SetResolution(Image.HorizontalResolution, Image.VerticalResolution);

            using (Bitmap Target = new Bitmap(Crop.Width, Crop.Height, Image.PixelFormat)) {
                Target.SetResolution(Image.HorizontalResolution, Image.VerticalResolution);

                using (Graphics Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(Target)) {
                    Graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                    Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    Graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.Pixel;
                    Graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                    Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

                    Graphics.DrawImage(Source, new Rectangle(0, 0, Target.Width, Target.Height), new Rectangle(Crop.Left, Crop.Top, Crop.Width, Crop.Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                };

                Target.Save(FileName, JpegCodecInfo, HighQualityEncoder);
            };
        };
    }

    public void CropAndResize(
        Product Product,
        Crop Crop) {
        using (Image Temp = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId))) {
            Img Img = new Img();

            this.ProductProvider.AddImageAndSave(Product, Img);

            this.Crop(String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId), Temp, Crop);

            using (Image Cropped = Image.FromFile(String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId))) {
                this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}-L.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), this.Sizes[0], Cropped, DefaultQualityEncoder);
                this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}-T.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), this.Sizes[1], Cropped, DefaultQualityEncoder);
                this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}-S.jpg", Path, Img.ImageId), this.Sizes[2], Cropped, DefaultQualityEncoder);
            };
        };

        this.Purge(Product);
    }

    public void QueueFor(
        Product Product,
        Size Size,
        HttpPostedFileBase PostedFile) {
        using (Image Image = Image.FromStream(PostedFile.InputStream)) {
            this.Resize(String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId), Size, Image, HighQualityEncoder);
        };
    }

    private void Purge(
        Product Product) {
        string Temp = String.Format("{0}/{1}.temp", Path, Product.ProductId);

        if (File.Exists(Temp)) {
            File.Delete(Temp);
        };

        foreach (Img Img in Product.Imgs) {
            string Cropped = String.Format("{0}/{1}.cropped", Path, Img.ImageId);

            if (File.Exists(Cropped)) {
                File.Delete(Cropped);
            };
        };
    }

    private void Resize(
        string FileName,
        Size Size,
        Image Image,
        EncoderParameters EncoderParameters) {
        if (Size.Height == 0) {
            Size.Height = (int)(Image.Height / ((float)Image.Width / (float)Size.Width));
        };

        using (Bitmap Bitmap = new Bitmap(Image, Size)) {
            Bitmap.Save(FileName, JpegCodecInfo, EncoderParameters);
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Regarding the black lines in the bottom is because you don't handle the Aspect Ratio.

```
double aspectRatio = imageWidth/imageHeight;
double boxRatio = maxWidth/maxHeight;
double scaleFactor = 0;
if (boxRatio > aspectRatio)
 //Use height, since that is the most restrictive dimension of box.
 scaleFactor = maxHeight / imageHeight;
else
 scaleFactor = maxWidth / imageWidth;

double newWidth = imageWidth * scaleFactor;
double newHeight = imageHeight * scaleFactor;
```

Source: http://nathanaeljones.com/163/20-image-resizing-pitfalls/

Comment: Well, based on the code in my update above, the black lines got fixed on their own, but I still appreciate your suggestion. Also, that article was quite good actually.

Comment: @Alex: The article saved me big time in a project :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess is that in your input/calculations, you are probably providing larger source rectangle than actually exists - for example, source image size 640 x 480 but while scaling (DrawImage call), it is getting passed as 640 x 479. Other way is also possible that destination rectangle is smaller than target bitmap - but it appears unlikely by looking at your code. Best way to trouble shoot is to put break-point and inspect source image size and compare it will source rectangle size (crop parameter)

Comment: I think the sizing issues were corrected when I switched to using the System.Drawing.Size and System.Drawing.Rectangle classes all the way through instead of substituting with my own classes.